# Is it possible to set a certain number of thumbnails for fotorama

Tags: fotorama

For example, I have 10 photos but i need to display only 4 thumbs. Now the width of thumb's wrapper takes width of fotorama.

Answer (score 0):

In the 4.5.0 new option was added, `navwidth`:

Have a look at fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/artpolikarpov/8xQhC/embedded/result,html,js/